# Is there a way to change the default overwrite to yes in the write.xlsx function of openxlsx?

Tags: r, overwrite, openxlsx

A new user has been given the job of running reports in R Studio but the reports have been written using `openxlsx` version 4.2.3 while the new user has `openxlsx` V 4.2.4. In 4.2.3 the default behaviour of the `write.xlsx` function is to overwrite an existing workbook, in 4.2.4 the default is to not overwrite an existing workbook.

Is there a way to change this default behaviour, or will I need to re-write all of the `write.xlsx` code lines in every report to include `overwrite = true?`

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to redefine `write.xlsx` like so. The following reprex first creates an example file, reads the file and then writes it again using the customized `write.xlsx` where I set `overwrite = TRUE` as default. As a result no error is thrown

```r
library(openxlsx)

# Make an example file
write.xlsx(head(mtcars), "mtcars.xlsx")

foo <- read.xlsx("mtcars.xlsx")

write.xlsx <- function(x, file) openxlsx::write.xlsx(x, file, overwrite = TRUE)

write.xlsx(foo, "mtcars.xlsx")
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>